# ConcurrentPerOrgApex Limit exceeded

Tags: apex, callout, governorlimits, future, queueable-interface

We are calling Queueable Interface from trigger to make multiple callouts to external systems. The number of callout from Queueable class is 50 as the other system can process only one record at a time. We have also allowed user to do mass update on the record so there can be multiple Queueable interface running at the same time. The issue is that we are getting "ConcurrentPerOrgApex Limit exceeded" error. This issue occurrs if there are more than 10 long running jobs(takes more than 5 sec to execute).
I would like to know few things:
1. Is there any alternative to implement the above requirement? Batch Apex is the solution but it cannot be real time.
2. Can this issue occur if we implement the same logic(50 callouts from future) using future methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the dan appleman advanced apex 3rd edition pattern chapter 7; all async requests go through a single chained queueable mechanism

Comment: We're running into this at the moment and it's really frustrating to me that queueable jobs try to execute and fail under this limit. This should be handled by the platform.